# Synchrounous execution of stored procedure

Tags: java, asynchronous, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have the following code:

```
connection = makeConnection();
CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call dbo.delete_orders(?) }");
callableStatement.setString(1, userName);
callableStatement.execute();
callableStatement.close();
```

Please help me to understand how I can guarantee that after last row execution stored procedure execution will be finished or it executes asynchronously.

Comment: Please show the code of that stored procedure. Exact behavior might depend on what the stored procedure does. For example if that stored procedure first selects from a table (returning that table) and then does the delete, then that delete operation might not occur unless the rows are actually read (I'm not sure if that is the case for SQL Server or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JDBC` does not support asynchronous executions.

But on the other hand `JDBC` also doesn't specify that calling (some of its methods like `execute()`) is blocking. That means that you may get (first) results from the database while it is still executing the query in background.

But this depends on the implementation of the `JDBC` driver *and* the Database itself.

Answer (score 0):

JDBC does not support asynchronous executions. If that's pure JDBC, then it should run synchronously.